# how to find first decile using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
country     2013    2014   2015   2016  2017   2018

Germany     65.5    66.5   67     67.5  67.7    68
France      65.5    65.5   66     67    67      68
india       64      67     68     68    67      67.5
japan       70      71     71.5   72    73      72.5
Australia   34      34     81     82    84      84
```

In 2018, below which life expectancy threshold a country is in the first decile (°)?

Can anyone please tell me how to find the first decile? or how to solve the above question?

Comment: can you tell the expected output ?

Comment: Also its not clear to me what do you mean by first line "In 2018 ....". Please elaborate a bit by modifying the question

Comment: As far as I know, the first decile is the point with 10% of data below it and 90% above it..

Comment: 2018 is the year column... which has life expectancy

Comment: Got it. Please share the piece of code that you have tried so that I can help with what you are doing wrong or where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

This uses boolean indexing together with [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html?highlight=qcut#pandas.qcut) to find the rows (countries) where the 2018 values fall in the first decile.

```
bins = 10  # Bin into deciles.
df[pd.qcut(df['2018'], bins, labels=range(bins)).eq(0)]
```

The result of `pd.qcut(df['2018'], bins, labels=range(bins))` will be a series where each row is in the 0-9 range indicating the bin number (deciles where 0 is the first first decile and 9 is the tenth decile).  Then we just want to find rows in the first deceile (where `bin` equals 0), which we do using a boolean mask (simplified, `df[decile_series.eq(0)]`).

Comment: Could you please elaborate your solution a bit?

Comment: okay I understood but my question is asking..below which threshold life expectancy the country is in the first decile...if I'm not wrong it is asking about a particular value of life expectancy below which the country is in the first decile. your solution is returning a dataframe with list of countries

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find the first decile among the life expectancy of countries across 2018?

A decile implies splitting up the countries into 10 equal subsections, so I assume you gave a small sample of the full list of countries.

To answer your question, to get deciles you can use pandas [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) function: this tries to divide up the underlying data into equal sized bins. The function defines the bins using percentiles based on the distribution of the data (assuming that is what you need).

Say your dataframe is called `df`.

```
pd.qcut(df['2018'], q=10)
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

we can do it in this way :

```
df['2018'].quantile(0.1)
```